# Short story about a kid who finds a robot and has it do his homework and chores

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, robots

This is a long shot but... in 7th grade (1995) I had a math substitute who read us a short story instead of class work. Here's what I remember.

A kid finds a robot on his way home from school. He quickly realizes it can clean his room and do his homework pretty well. In no time, he has it doing extra chores to help his parents out, double checking his homework, even answering his mom's exhausting questions like "how was school today". Life is awesome.

Then the story addresses the reader like, "What would you have the robot do? Wouldn't you love to have a robot like that? Actually - you do! **You** can do all the things your robot would do. etc"

It was a mind explosion for my middle school brain. I'd love to share it with my kids if I could find it.

Comment: Apparently this is no longer science fiction. Phoebe Zhang reports that machines can do handwriting exercises for students [(_Inkstone_, Feb. 20, 2019)](https://www.inkstonenews.com/tech/chinese-robot-copying-machine-causes-online-debate/article/3000875).

Comment: If a story is science fiction when its written, it is science fiction forever, even if all the futuristic inventions in it became real, everyday household objects.  All science fiction stories with futuristic gadgets like television and automobiles are still science fiction even now that television and automobiles exist.  All science fiction stories about the first Moon landing are still science fiction stories even more than 50 years after the real first Moon landing.